# how to avoid the brackets appearing in the generated method statement

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to do an assign statement while trying to generate some c# code using codedom.

Here are the statements I wrote:

```
inputmethod.Name = "CaptureInput";
inputmethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
inputmethod.Parameters.Add(
    new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(string[]), "inputs"));

inputmethod.Statements.Add(
    new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(
            new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
                new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "ColA")
            , CodeBinaryOperatorType.Assign
            , new CodeArrayIndexerExpression(
            new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("inputs"),
            new CodePrimitiveExpression(0))));
```

When it generates I'm getting a line that goes like:

```
(this.ColA = input [0]);
```

Compiler finds fault with above line, `CS0201`

How to remove the bracket in the generated output?

Comment: It looks as if the generated line is part of a method call. Is that what the inputMethod is?

Comment: Its a CodeMemberMethod...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets are part of the BinaryOperatorExpression. Don't remove them.

Use the [CodeAssignStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeassignstatement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of the CodeBinaryOperatorExpression.

```
inputmethod.Statements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(
    new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("ColA"),
    new CodeArrayIndexerExpression(
        new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("inputs"),
        new CodePrimitiveExpression(0))));
```